# Можно ли поставить картинки в подменю приложения андройд?

Tags: java, изображения, android

Можно ли поставить картинки в подменю приложения андройд,если записываю в хml файле его описание и назначаю картинку - не работает. Что может быть не так?

Comment: мне кажется, вам надо показать, что вы пишете.

Comment: да, можно, добавьте вот это туда, и вот это туда.    
ну как, получилось? Ой, что это? Вы что, не обладаете телепатией? Как неловко вышло... Я вот тоже не обладаю, и что вы называете "подменю приложения андройд" (к слову, андроИд пишется через "и"), увы, понять не могу... Будьте добры, утрудитесь объяснить, и  код вашего XML файла тоже выложите.

Answer (score 1):

Картинки в подменю добавляются посредством добавления пунктов меню и установкой у них иконки, как в этом примере( в XML варианте разберетесь без труда и сами ):

```
SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(0, 0, Menu.NONE, "Submenu1");
MenuItem item = sub1.add(0, 0, Menu.NONE+1, "Item");
item.setIcon( android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete );
```

В итоге будет подменю с одним пунктом, у которого будет иконка(в данном случае - мусорная корзина).

**Для потомков:**

Начиная с API Level 21 привычные "иконки" меню мигрировали в ActionBar.
Подробнее можно ознакомиться [тут](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).